# Use Globals in email templates

Tags: emails, globals

I’ve set up a few email notifications to be sent to customers, and in the corresponding email templates I’d like to use content from Global fields I’ve created.

But when I use the regular variable `{{ globalSetHandle.fieldHandle }}` nothing is outputted in the emails.

Does that means that we can’t use Globals inside email templates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't loaded into the twig template global scope but you can access them with:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.globals#getSetByHandle